# Polymer 1.0 Data Binding to rowspan attribute

Tags: polymer

I'm creating dynamic data driven tables with Polymer 1.0 using data binding:

```
  <tbody>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{instInfo}}" as="instItem">
      <tr>
        <td rowspan="{{instItem.rowSpan}}">{{instItem.name}}</td>
      </tr>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{instItem.rows}}" as="row">
        <tr>
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{row}}" as="rowItem">
            <td>{{rowItem}}</td>
          </template>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </template>
  </tbody>
```

All of the data bindings above work fine except for the td rowpsan (line 4). When I use a real number, all is well. 
Is data binding to an html attribute possible?

Answer (score 2):

Use `attribute$="{{value}}"` rather than `attribute="{{value}}"`.

Per the [polymer documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding):

> To bind to an attribute, use `$=` rather than `=`. This results in a call to:
>
> `element.setAttribute(attr, value);`
>
> As opposed to:
>
> `element.property = value;`

Comment: You can also bind to the property itself via `row-span="{{value}}"` (because the property uses camel-case [`rowSpan`], the dash is required).